# What is the meaning of {} \; in find -exec sed

Tags: sed

Given two examples of sed.

```
sed -i 's/ugly/beautiful/g' /home/bruno/old-friends/sue.txt
```

This is easy for me to understand.

But this:

```
$ find /home/bruno/old-friends -type f -exec sed -i 's/ugly/beautiful/g' {} \;
```

Why is `{} \;` important in the second one? What the significance and meaning of this?
I assume `;' is for -exec. But why should it be escaped and what does the braces mean? Can they be imagined to be similar to C function's scope?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not actually for `sed`, it's for `find`. That line is telling `find` to find matching files and, when it finds them, execute `sed`. The `{}` is where the filename will be on the `sed` command line, and the `\;` marks the end of the `sed` command line. (In theory you could then continue with other `find` actions; they would only happen if `sed` returned `0`.)

So if `find` finds the file `/home/foo/bar`, the `sed` command line will be

```
sed -i 's/ugly/beautiful/g' /home/foo/bar
```

Comment: Thanks and do you know the the reason we escape `;`? Interesting choice of {} for doing substitution of filename.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran: We have to escape `;` because in most shells, `;` is used to separate commands. (Try `echo "a" ; echo "b"` in your shell, for instance.) So if we didn't escape it, it wouldn't be an argument to `find`, it would be the end of that command and the beginning of the next, at the shell level.

Comment: Thanks! I did not think about shell's need. It makes sense now.